# How to pass different values to XML node before passing to HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I am new to C# and got a question. I am writing automation test for SOAP web service using HttpWebRequest and I am passing XML to request and getting XML back as string.

Now, I am trying to pass this request XML saved in file but wants to change XML node values. I am thinking of having different test data from an Excel sheet and then passing that data to XML nodes.

I can do this if I saved all XML request in a string object within a class but I want to read request from XML file.

I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to parameterize XML and send to a webservice. Easiest way is to create a template XML with placeholders and then at run-time replace the placeholders with data from excel, as shown below.

XML:

```
<Name>
 <FirstName>{{FirstName}}</FirstName>
 <LastName>{{LastName}}</LastName>
</Name>
```

Excel/CSV

```
FirstName,LastName
FName1,LName1
FName2,LName2
```

You can now read the values from the excel as a dictionary and do something like below.

C# Code Illustration:

```
foreach(KeyValuePair kvp in dictionary)
 {
  xml = xml.Replace("{{" + kvp.key + "}}", kvp.value)
}
```

If the XML parameterization is not feasible, you can navigate to the XML nodes using XPath (Use any of the XML holder objects) and set the node values.